# why when I set default value for item in a form the CREATE button disappear?

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using oracle APEX and I want to set default value for some items in a form like

```
BRANCH_ID
```

I save BRANCH_ID at login process

```
select :P9999_BRANCH_ID into :P0_BRANCH_ID from dual;
```

when I set the default value for the BRANCH_ID and run the form the
CREATE button disappeared and
DELETE and APPLY CHANGES button appeared instead of CREATE button ,

when I removed the default value and run the form in CREATE mode its appear again .

I tried also to set default value by using before header process
but same thing when run the form CREATE button disappear

How can I set default value for item and keep CREATE button only in INSERT mode ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're doing it wrong. `BRANCH_ID` column *smells* like a primary key column. If that form is e.g. called from an Interactive Report, it (the report) passes the ID value to form so that Pre-Rendering process knows which values to retrieve from the database.

If you pre-populate `BRANCH_ID`, then it already contains some value.

It means that **Server-side conditions** on buttons (CREATE, DELETE, APPLY_CHANGES) conclude that `BRANCH_ID` already has a value, which also means that row exists in the underlying table, so:

- CREATE button isn't rendered because row already exists; you can't create a new one with the same ID, so - CREATE is *hidden*
- DELETE and APPLY_CHANGES are rendered because row exists, so you can either delete it or modify it (and then save changes)

---

I believe you shouldn't set that item's value in any process - let Apex handle it. Set other items' values, if you want.

If you still want to do it, then **review Server-side conditions** on all those buttons and modify them so that buttons are shown when certain conditions - set by you - are met.

---

**[EDIT]**

Create a **process** which will set values; set it to fire before automatic row processing. For example:

```
:P1_BRANCH_ID    := NVL(:P1_BRANCH_ID, SEQ.NEXTVAL);
:P1_CREATED_BY   := :APP_USER;
:P1_CREATED-DATE := SYSDATE;
```

Comment: thank you for reply its clear I will change the primary key to be for example ID and identity column , yes I have composite primary key now (BRANCH_ID for customer and CUSTOMER_ID ) when I create new file for customer I need to get BRANCH_ID automatic from the login information the user BRANCH_ID from login window ,

Comment: actually I need to use this value before insert to the database like if I want to insert new row to the database I need the following columns value to be inserted automatically (BRANCH_ID , CREATED_BY , CREATED_DATE ) how to set these values , before in oracle forms we create global variables and set its value after login or in PRE-INSERT trigger , how to assign these values before insert in oracle APEX ?

Comment: thank you so much its working but sorry I have another issue please I added new region interactive grid for details table below the form region and I want to assign value for the hidden columns in the grid but its not appear the grid columns appear without number like form columns for example form column can be assigned in the process like this :P1_CREATED_BY   := :APP_USER;
 but grid column cannot assign when type CREATED_BY   := :APP_USER  it shows error ora-06550 identifier must be declared CREATED_BY how to do it please for interactive grid columns ?

Comment: Navigate to Interactive Grid columns' properties and set their **default value**.

Answer (score 1):

Something looks a bit off in your logic. It seems you're trying to preset the primary key value before the form is initialized and that is causing the behaviour that the form goes into "Update" mode instead of "Create" mode and that is causing the behaviour you're seeing.

If you really want to preset the primary key value, you should do that in a computation after submit (didn't test it but pretty sure that will work), however, it makes a lot more sense to have the database handle the primary key values for you. That way no code to generate primary key values is needed in the application. The most "modern" way is to use *identity columns*, a more "classic" way is to use a *before update trigger* on the table.

Comment: thank you so much I will try it , yes I have composite primary key now (BRANCH_ID for customer and CUSTOMER_ID ) when I create new file for customer I need to get BRANCH_ID automatic from the login information the user BRANCH_ID from login window